# Filtering CSV file like SQL in PHP

Tags: php, csv, sorting, filter, foreach

I have a CSV file containing multiple columns, I would like to sort and filter like I do with SQL.

CSV structure -

```
Type  |  Vin  | DateInStock
New   |  675F |   12/06/19
Used  |  7643 |   12/05/19

etc..
```

Here is my PHP file -

```
$fh = fopen('myFile.csv', 'r');
while($line = fgetcsv($fh)) {
    $type[] = array($line[0]); 
    $vin[] = array($line[1]); 
    $date[] = array($line[2]); 
}
```

So What I would normally do is

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = 'Used' AND date = '$todays_date'";
```

Then echo out all the Vin numbers

```
$vin = $row['vin'];
```

I can get an array of the type, vin and date but not sure how to just display vin's that are from todays date and have a type of Used. What would I do to accomplish this? I tried this for just getting vin numbers with the type Used -

```
  foreach($type as $t){
      $recall_type = $t[0];
      if($recall_type == 'Used'){
          foreach ( $vin as $value ){
              $recall_vin = $value[0];    
              $recall_vin.'<br>';
          } 
      } 
   }
```

But that just echos out the same vin pattern hundreds of times..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would read all the values into a single multidimensional array; then you can filter that using [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) based on the criteria you have. For example:

```
$fh       = fopen('myFile.csv', 'r');
$vehicles = array();
while($line = fgetcsv($fh)) {
    $vehicles[] = array(
                        'type' => $line[0], 
                        'vin'  => $line[1], 
                        'date' => $line[2]
                        );
}
// get today's date in a format to match the CSV
$today = date('m/d/y');
$vehicles = array_filter($vehicles, function ($v) use ($today) { 
    return $v['type'] == 'Used' && $v['date'] == $today;
});
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/mBbFt)

Comment: Thank you, Where is $v being declared? Im a little confused.. Im not to familiar with multidimensional arrays

Comment: @RyanD `$v` is a dummy variable which represents the current value of the array as `array_filter` iterates through it.

Comment: Ok cool, It returns a blank page, when I print out $vehicles the multidimensional array is correct and has the the correct values. Do I need to do something with the return value? sorry for being a noob..

Comment: @RyanD see my edit, I've added a link to a demo; as you can see `$vehicles` has only the matching vehicle after the call to `array_filter`

Comment: It has to do with return  $v['type'] == 'Used' && $v['date'] == $today; If I remove && == $today I get the results in an array. I checked the date format and they are the correct format

Comment: Yes I found the issue, I had $today - 12/06/2019 and the format in the CSV is 12/6/2019 Thanks mate much appreciated and thanks for the great explanation!